# Web Scraping using Puppeteer returns undefined during atcoder contest

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I made a web scrapper for parsing test cases of Atcoder contest. It works well if the contest is already finished but gives an error for an **ongoing** contest. The error arises when accessing the `rows` of the `table` HTML element. I am positive that the table exists but for some reason, the script returns undefined for an **ongoing** contest.

Error:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:32
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (/mnt/d/c++/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:229:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/mnt/d/c++/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:107:16)
    at async scrapeSite (/mnt/d/c++/codeforces/atcoder.js:57:33)
```

Here is my Scrapper: atcoder.js:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

const contest_id = process.argv[2];

async function scrapeProblem(problem_letter) {
    const url = `https://atcoder.jp/contests/${contest_id}/tasks/${contest_id}_${problem_letter.toLowerCase()}`;
    console.log(url);
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

        const samples_scraped = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const samples = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
            const scraped = Array.from(samples).filter((child) => {
                return child.id !== "";
            });
            let num_scraped = scraped.length;
            // The elements were repeated twice, so remove the extra elements
            for (let i = 0; i < num_scraped / 2; i++) scraped.pop();
            return scraped.map((ele) => ele.innerText);
            // return Array.from(samples).map((child) => child.innerText);
        });

        let id = 1;
        // Now we need to store the samples in text format
        samples_scraped.map((ele, idx) => {
            if (idx % 2 == 0) {
                // Input
                fs.writeFile(`${problem_letter}-${id}.in`, ele, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            } else {
                // Output
                fs.writeFile(`${problem_letter}-${id}.out`, ele, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
                id++;
            }
            return ele;
        });
        await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

async function scrapeSite() {
    const url = `https://atcoder.jp/contests/${contest_id}/tasks`;
    console.log(url);
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

        // Returns all the problem letters
        const problem_letters = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const table = document.querySelectorAll("table")[0];
            const rows = table.rows.length;
            const letters = [];

            for (let i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
                letters.push(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText);
            }

            return letters;
        });

        console.log(problem_letters);

        for (problem_letter of problem_letters) {
            scrapeProblem(problem_letter);
        }

        await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

scrapeSite();
```

The `scrapeProblem(problem_letter)` is a helper function to scrape the test cases for the given problem letter. It then stores the test cases to the user's file system using `fs` module.

The `scrapeSite()` function first parses the homepage for the number of problems and the problem letter associated with each problem. It then calls the `scrapeProblem(problem_letter)` helper function to parse the required web site for test cases.

To run the script: `node scrapper.js abc280`

Update: I tried it in a new contest and again got the same error. This time I took a screenshot using Puppeteer and found out the problem. I am getting permission denied if I try to accesss the site without logging in for an ongoing contest.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the site requires us to login and only then we can see the problem statements of an **ongoing** contest. So I added a function which will first login to the site and then it will proceed to parse the test cases.

Updated code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");
require('dotenv').config();

const contest_id = process.argv[2];

async function login(browser, page) {
    const url = `https://atcoder.jp/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fatcoder.jp%2F`;
    console.log("Logging in..", url);
    try {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

        await page.type('#username', process.env.USERNAME);
        await page.type("#password", process.env.PASSWORD);
        await page.click("#submit");

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Login failed...");
        console.log(e);
    }
}

async function scrapeProblem(browser, Problem) {
    const url = Problem.Url;
    console.log(url);
    try {
        // const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        // await login(browser, page);
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

        const samples_scraped = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const samples = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
            const scraped = Array.from(samples).filter((child) => {
                return child.id !== "";
            });
            let num_scraped = scraped.length;
            // The elements were repeated twice, so remove the extra elements
            for (let i = 0; i < num_scraped / 2; i++) scraped.pop();
            return scraped.map((ele) => ele.innerText);
            // return Array.from(samples).map((child) => child.innerText);
        });

        let id = 1;
        // Now we need to store the samples in text format
        samples_scraped.map((ele, idx) => {
            if (idx % 2 == 0) {
                // Input
                fs.writeFile(`${Problem.Problem_letter}-${id}.in`, ele, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            } else {
                // Output
                fs.writeFile(`${Problem.Problem_letter}-${id}.out`, ele, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
                id++;
            }
            return ele;
        });

        // await browser.close();

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

async function scrapeSite() {
    const url = `https://atcoder.jp/contests/${contest_id}/tasks`;
    console.log(url);
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await login(browser, page);
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

        // await page.screenshot({ path: "./screenshot.png", fullPage: true});

        // Returns all the problem letters
        const problems = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const table = document.querySelectorAll("table")[0];
            const rows = table.rows.length;
            const letters = [];

            for (let i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
                letters.push({Problem_letter: table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText, Url: table.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.href });
            }

            return letters;
        });

        console.log(problems);
        const promises = []

        for (problem of problems) {
            promises.push(scrapeProblem(browser, problem));
        }

        await Promise.all(promises);    // All the promises must be resolved before closing the browser

        await browser.close();

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

scrapeSite();
```